# Identical accuracy in different ML Classification models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I used the "***Stroke***" data set from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset) to compare the accuracy of the following different models of classification:

1. `K-Nearest-Neighbor (KNN)`.
2. `Decision Trees`.
3. `Adaboost`.
4. `Logistic Regression`.

I did not implement the models myself, but used sklearn library's implementations.
After training the models I ran the test data and printed the level of accuracy of each of the models and these are the results:
[image]

As you can see, `KNN`, `Adaboost`, and `Logistic Regression` gave me the exact same accuracy.

My question is, does it make sense that there is not even a small difference between them or did I make a mistake somewhere along the way (Even though I only used `sklearn`'s implementations?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Comment: Please notice that SO is about *programming* questions; for such non-programming ML questions see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut I'll keep that in mind. with that been said, there is a fine line between the the 2 topics. I mean, my main question is about the code I've wrote and `sklearn` library.
Anyway, I will delete the follow-up question I've added in the end of the post because as you mentioned, this question is theoretical and non-programming related.

Comment: @desertnaut please let me know if you think the question is ok now after editing it.
I am relativly new to SO and still learning it's rules:)

Comment: Your question does not contain any code, so by definition it cannot be about programming in the sense used here in SO. Still, it seems to me you are asking a general theoretical/methodological question on if (and how) such a situation *might* be possible. The answer below kinda confirms this, i.e. it is a quite general one, with mostly theoretical guidelines ("*You may have a bug in reporting or processing*" does not qualify as a programming answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general achieving the same scores is unlikely, and the explanation is usually:

- bug in actual reporting
- bug in the data processing
- **score reported corresponds to a degenerate solution**

And the last explanation is probably the case. Stroke dataset has 249 positive samples in 5000 datapoints, so if your model always says "no stroke" it will get roughly 95%. So my best guess is that all your models failed to learn anything and are just constantly outputting "0".

In general accuracy is not a right metric for highly imabalnced datasets. Consider balanced accuracy, f1, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I Think you are right suggesting that the data structre could cause this results. 
that been said, I think its not a problem with the models or the learning process, because, as I said, Its `sklearn`'s models.

I think what may cause this is the fact that the data is to small for good learning and for that reason the 3 models fail to predict the same "hard to predict" samples.
does that make any scense?

Comment: Implementation can be correct but model can still fail. You need to tune hyperparameters, change losses etc. for highly imbalanced problems very few things work "off the shelf"